# How to add multi-core features to a game engine that was created to run on a single core?

Tags: c++

I'd like to turn old game engines (such as *Doom engine*/*id Tech 1*) that were designed to run on a single core computer into multi-core game engines.

How can I do that?

Comment: The performance gain of an application is tied to the ratio of thread/cores, but the number of thread in an application is not limited by the number of cores. What makes you think that adding threads to an app that runs on only one core would be different than an app that runs on multiple cores?

Comment: Well take the doom engine from id software that brought us doom in the 90's  is it possible to edit the game engine to run off multi cores instead of 1 core any advice on that question if so how would somebody go about any game engine that came out in the 90's to add multi core support

Comment: Find one component that doesn't need lock-step synchronization with your core engine (Ragdoll Physics, Pathfinding, Particles, etc) and run it on a separate thread. (You'll need to synchronize periodically, like when you need to update a mesh used by the renderer after a simulation step is complete, and that synchronization part needs to be wrapped in a critical region so as to not disturb the rest of your non-threadsafe engine)

Comment: Jimmy is there any tutorials out there for doing this kind of thing like you said.

Comment: Jimmy can you post a code example of what you are saying.

Comment: Much as I love posting code examples, this is something that doesn't really work in an example. The explanation is already as general as possible. If you *really* want an example, look at https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/203543_203543.pdf

Comment: There are probably not any tutorials for something like this.  What you want to do is actually one of the harder tasks in the entire world of programming.  Those who have the skillset to do this do not need a tutorial, so it will be hard to find one.  My advice would be to start by learning to do multi-threaded programming, write a few application using it, then look at porting single-threaded code to become more multi-threaded.  Around that time you'll understand how multithreading works well enough to phrase a question like this more precicely.

Comment: Very True Cort Ammon well I must have picked the hardest one to ask lol anyway thank you all so much for your generous advice and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just edit the binary or configuration files of some already-compiled game written under single-threaded assumptions to turn it into a game that effectively utilizes more than one thread. Unless the code has some existing multithreaded features that were just shipped disabled, making this kind of change requires access to the source code. The switch to a multi-threaded computation model from a single-threaded computation model is non-trivial, which is part of why it continues to be so [difficult](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/concurrency-ddj.htm).

If you have access to the source code of the game in question, making this transition is done exactly the same way as you would in building a game to leverage multi-threading in the first place. It will probably be harder because you will first need to learn the existing code base *and* work around a lot of fundamental design challenges stemming from the fact that the original code probably did not bother to consider concurrency.

The basic process will involve identifying portions of the code that can be rewritten to execute in parallel, and then performing that refactoring. The specifics of the tasks will vary based on the specifics of the code and problems you're dealing with; entire books can be written on the general topic of effective design under concurrency scenarios.